# Counting number of longest increasing subsequences by evolving recursive solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

How can I count the number of longest increasing LIS by evolving my recursive solution for example `[1,3,5,4,7]` returns `2` where the LIS is `1,3,5,7` and `1,3,4,7`similarly for `[3,3,3,3]` it will be `4` where LIS is `3` and there are `4` of them

I compute LIS recursively as follows: (I can optimize this using memoisation and go further to DP and then to a segmented tree as per various solutions but I would like to intuitively lead myself to them)

```
int numberOfLis(vector<int>& nums)
{
    //Set the size of count to the size of num, since there cannot be an LIS greater than the size of nums
    vector<int> count(nums.size(), 0); 

    //Get the size of the maximum LIS and update the frequency of how many similar sizes have been encountered in the count array
    int maxcount = LIS(nums, INT32_MIN, 0, count);

    //Return the number of occurances by looking it up in our count.
    return count[maxcount];
}

int LIS(vector<int>& nums, int prev, int index, vector<int>& count)
{
    if (index == nums.size()) return 0;

    int with = 0;
    //Increasing sequence, lets select it.
    if (nums[index] > prev) with = 1 + helper(nums, nums[index], index + 1, count);

    //See if we can do better without the current number
    int without = helper(nums, prev, index + 1, count);

    //Get the maximum seen so far and update the frequency in count array
    int maxcount = max(with, without);
    ++count[maxcount];

    return maxcount;
}
```

I used a `count` array `vector<int>(nums.size(), 0)` to increment the max value as I encounter it as `++count[max(with,without)]` where the `count` of the returned max value would be the answer. This lead the `count` array to have `4` a count of `1` not `2` which is wrong. I am looking for a way to move forward from here.

**Updated**: Added code for the `count` array and added comments

Comment: It would be worth while to mention why is this being down voted, either I could improve the question or provide the missing information.

Comment: You talk about incrementing a `count` value, and that vector having an incorrect value in it.  But `count` is not in the code that you've posted, so we can only speculate on what the problem might be.  Add your usage of `count` into the posted code.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I assumed the description would suffice, I didn't think that was a necessary piece of information, very naive of me. Added the code for count.

Comment: It might help to name entities for their *raison d'être* - `count` just informs about the operations its elements are subjected to, `helper()` is as useless as `f13()`. [(doc) comment](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html) your code!

Comment: @greybeard added comments

Answer (score 1):

The count for a subsequence is more than an increment, as there can be multiple subsequences that end up with the same length.

Working with your example data, when `index` is 1, both `with` and `without` are 3.  `count[3]` is only incremented once, though, even though there are two subsequences with this length, and 3 is returned as the maximum length.  When this is used by the previous call (when `index` is 0), `with` will be 4 and `without` 3.  `count[4]` is only increased by 1, even though there are two subsequences of length 4.

You need to change `helper` to return not just the length of the longest subsequence, but the number of subsequences that have that length.

Comment: return a pair at each step you mean? wouldn't updating ++count[with] and ++count[without] lead to the solution?

Comment: @SamerTufail Incrementing count isn't right, because when `index` is 0, `with` is 4 and `without` is 3 (there are two subsequences of length 4 after stepping to index 1).

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the longest increasing subsequence length starting at kth element of the array.

Then, using this data use something like:

```
int numberoflis(int k){
     if(LIS(k)==1) return 1;
     int ret = 0;
     for(int i=k+1; i<N; ++i){
         if(A[i] > A[k] && LIS(i) == LIS(k)-1){
             ret += numberoflis(i);
         }
     }
     return ret;
 }
```

Now you have number of longest increasing subsequences starting at point k. Use a simple loop to figure out the total number of LISs. Also, you should memoize this - but it is easy.

Comment: Is this supposed to be `LIS(i) == LIS(k-1)` ?

Comment: @SamerTufail nope. In the loop, we look for continuations of the longest increasing subsequence. We look for array elements after the current element, that are greater than the current element, and that have the longest increasing subsequence just 1 element shorter than the current element's sequence.